# Conflicting different country laws when browsing the Internet, as you connect to servers worldwide

Tags: copyright, criminal-law, internet, international

When a user browses the Internet, downloads or views content and websites, which law are they under, the law from its own country, from where they are browsing the Internet, or the law from the country that particular website, Cloud or CDN is based in.
For example, if an user from *Country A* downloads a file which is considered legal in his own country from a Cloud Service or a CDN which is based in *Country B* where that content is ruled illegal, would someone be prosecuted? The user would be prosecuted, although that content its legal in his country of residence *Country A*?

Answer (score 0):

If country A thinks they could and should prosecute you, and they can lay their hands on you, then they will. And the same is true for country B, C and D.

It seems you are describing a situation where A is fine with what you did, so they won’t prosecute. B seems to think what you did is wrong, but many countries don’t care about people breaking the law outside that country, so B would likely not want to prosecute you. Even if they wanted to, they don’t have you, and A won’t extradite you, so you are likely safe.